# How to resolve the sonar issue "Correctness - This method continues a loop after finding an equality condition "

Tags: java, java-8, sonarqube

I have below code. All i wanted from the code is

1. if supplied locale in the method argument is present in labelList, return it
   or
2. check if EN_US is present in labelList, then return it

```
 String LOCALE = "locale"; 
 List<Map<String, Object>> labelList = // coming for other class
...
 public Object resolveData(String locale) {
 Map<String, Object> enUSLabel = null;
         locale = locale!= null && !locale.isEmpty() ? locale: EN_US;
              for (Map<String, Object> picklistLabel : labelList) {
                if (picklistLabel.get(LOCALE).equals(locale)) {
                  return picklistLabel;
                } else if (EN_US.equals(picklistLabel.get(LOCALE))) {
                  enUSLabel = picklistLabel;
                }
              }
              return enUSLabel;
 }
```

I am getting sonar issue (at enUSLabel = picklistLabel;)

Correctness - This method continues a loop after finding an equality condition
This method continues with a loop, and does not break out of it, after finding and setting a variable in an if condition based on equality. Since continuing on in the loop would seem to be unlikely to find the item again, breaking at this point would seem to be the proper action.

How to correct it ? Is it possible in one for loop ?

Comment: are you looking to the last result of the first one?

Comment: @Fildor I dont understand. If i supplied de locale, but if it is not present in labelList ? then how will i get enUS locale ?

Comment: Just return it. No, wait... What if none of which is present in the list? You want to return `null` then?

Comment: @YCF_L Can you elaborate

Comment: @Fildor  yes return null

Comment: Consider eliminating the redundancy of calling `picklistLabel.get(LOCALE)` twice, e.g. by creating another local variable. Besides that, I don’t consider this code wrong. Don’t waste time rewriting valid code, just because some tool tells you. This tool is only applying pattern matching, following rules some other guys have given it. There is no reason to assume that all contributors to these rules were smarter than you. In this specific case, the rule might be useful, but the associated pattern is too broad.

Comment: After trying to fix my answer, I think Holger has a point here. Readability could be improved, but technically, it works, right?

Comment: Agree. You don't have to agree with everything that SonarQube says. You can suppress them with a SuppressWarnings annotation. I've had cases where SonarQube reported an issue, but it was invalid because of certain limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `enUSLabel = picklistLabel` with `return picklistLabel`